# Mocking expected result from service using spring testing framework

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-mvc, spring-test-mvc

I want to write a test case for `Restful web service` using `Spring testing framework`. I mocked the service and able to run the testcase successfully.

But, as service is mocked, it is returning the empty response. So, I want to set the expected output from the service.

I can achieve it using different mocking frameworks like `Mockito` or `Jmockit` (In below code it is with Mockito).

But, is it possible `without any addition/external testing frameworks` apart from internal `Spring testing framework`.

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

import java.util.Arrays;

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.model;


@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestContext.class, WebAppContext.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class TodoControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private TodoService todoServiceMock;

    @Test
    public void findAll_ShouldAddTodoEntriesToModelAndRenderTodoListView() throws Exception {

        Todo first = new TodoBuilder()
                .id(2L)
                .description("Lorem ipsum")
                .title("Bar")
                .build();

    /**
    Need mocking technique from Spring Testing Framework
    */
        when(todoServiceMock.findAll()).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(first));

        mockMvc.perform(get("/"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(view().name("todo/list"))
                .andExpect(forwardedUrl("/WEB-INF/jsp/todo/list.jsp"))
                .andExpect(model().attribute("todos", hasSize(2)))
                .andExpect(model().attribute("todos", hasItem(
                        allOf(
                                hasProperty("id", is(1L)),
                                hasProperty("description", is("Lorem ipsum")),
                                hasProperty("title", is("Foo"))
                        )
                )))
                .andExpect(model().attribute("todos", hasItem(
                        allOf(
                                hasProperty("id", is(2L)),
                                hasProperty("description", is("Lorem ipsum")),
                                hasProperty("title", is("Bar"))
                        )
                )));
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see Mockito in your example code, or the initialization of mockMvc either. Could you include a working example, or something that would hilight where you use Mockito?

Comment: Thank you for response. It is a working example @eis. when(todoServiceMock.findAll()).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(first)); is Mockito statement, where 'when' is the static import of Mockito jar. mockMvc is initialised as a private instance variable.

Comment: it's not working as-is as it needs other classes as well, I meant a standalone example.

Comment: updated with imports now... add dependencies of org.mockito|mockito-core and org.springframework|spring-test too... I should achieve this without mockito..

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to extend a class that you want to test and override methods that you want to mock up. Then in a separate configuration file you define a bean which would be wired in place of a real object. Next use this configuration in your test class.

This is actually Mockito spy's behaviour. If I were you I would stick to it as it provides more flexibility and saves a lot of boilerplate code.

Comment: it's one possible solution, but I would recommend against this. You shouldn't be extending classes you want to test, you should have dependencies wired through their interfaces and have test doubles that implement those interfaces instead. Then use Spring configuration to wire those test doubles.

Comment: I reckon that making interfaces for each bean is an overshot in some cases. You can call it good practice but sometimes it leads to creation of plenty unnecessary interfaces. I prefer using interfaces when they are really needed, not just because 'it's right'. So imo it's opinion based.

Comment: I agree that it's opinion based. I'm of the opinion that even those "unnecessary" interfaces tend to add considerably to the maintainability of the software, even if those interfaces would have only one implementation - they allow documenting clearly what is the actual public API that we want to expose and what is the role we choose to use the object for. Of course, if the interface is just autogenerated from public methods, there isn't much thinking or role consideration going on. I do agree that autogenerated interfaces identical to public api of the class don't provide that much benefit.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't showing the relevant part of your configuration, but it should be fully possible. In your `TodoService` you should have injected your data layer dependencies using their *interfaces* as per Spring best practices, and those dependencies can be replaced (using Spring config) with dummy/stub classes implementing those interfaces that provide the required test data.